# How can I make this test pass in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a Jasmine unit test and in it I have this 'expect'...

```
       expect(mockService.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new ToDoItem('a@b.com', 'get milk'));
```

In my controller I have the following...

```
        todoService.create($scope.newToDo, 
           function() {

        }, function() {

        });
```

But I always get an error because of the final two functions that I pass the service for success and failure. How can I stop this from happening? How do I add them to the expect clause?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the same instance of the todo object that was passed into create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use [`jasmine.any(Function)`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_<code>jasmine.any</code>), or [`jasmine.objectContaining`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Partial_Matching_with_<code>jasmine.objectContaining</code>).

Fair warning, I've never done this myself. However, from the documentation, at least one of them should provide the behaviour you want.

Comment: This should work. Was just typing up the answer... `expect(mockService.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new ToDoItem('a@b.com', 'get milk'), jasmine.any(Function), jasmine.any(Function));`

Comment: This was the best answer you should answer :-)